# UBUNTU 14.04 LTS Date and time is not displaying in the menu bar after login

Tags: lightdm

At the time of login, it displaying date and time in menu bar, once I logged in It disapears from the menu bar.

I have tried these mentioned below:

First approach:

- sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime
- sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
- sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata

Also tried :

- sudo restart lightdm

Please suggest me what can I do resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does indicator-datetime show up in your task manager?

If not, open a terminal and try typing

```
nohup indicator-datetime &
```

See if it shows up.  If so, then you need to add it to start automatically each time you restart.  You can do this by searching "Startup Applications" in dash, and adding indicator-datetime to the list.

I am unsure why it would not be starting on its own, but this is a possible workaround.

Comment: well checked in system monitor, process is there for indicator-datetime-service. and after that when try to add indicator-datetime in startup it asks for startup command, and gives pop up-"The startup command cannot be empty". please suggest.

Comment: I run xubuntu, so don't have a working system in front of me to test adding items using Ubuntu's startup applications app.  Hopefully someone else will chime in.

Did the date and time return to the menubar when you started the process manually?

Comment: nope, dint worked when used the above mentioned command. but yes checked the system monitor process was there for indicator-datetime-service.